# Why can't I access a variable that's inside an If statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

Here's the IF statement. I want to access the timeStampCleaned variable later on.

```
    if ($xmlRatesTime = '') {
        $timeStampCleaned = date('j F Y H:i', $ratesTimeStamp); // Convert unix timestamp into date format
    } else {
        // ...
    }
```

Like so:

```
    if(empty($ratesTimeStamp)) {

        $newXML = simplexml_load_file('cache/rates.xml');

        $child = $newXML->addChild('currency');
        $child->addAttribute('id', ''.$to.'');
        $child->addChild('title', $toTitle);
        $child->addChild('loc', $toLocation);
        $child->addChild('rate', $finalRate);
        $child->addChild('timestamp', $timeStamp);

        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $dom->loadXML($newXML->asXML());
        $newXMLdomCleaned = $dom->saveXML();

        file_put_contents('cache/rates.xml', $newXMLdomCleaned);
    }
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: timeStampCleaned in ...file... on line 208
```

From what I understand, accessing variables within if statements is fine. So I have no idea why this isn't working!?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to get `timeStampCleaned` variable? Not in the code you pasted.

Comment: IF statements are conditional so if the first time you use that variable is inside your IF statement (i.e. it is defined there) then you have to ensure it was actually called. If your IF statement skips over it, when you use it later it will be undefined.

Comment: Thanks cillosis. Also - what the hell is up with the down votes? I have a problem and I'm asking for help? jeez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because you are not declaring the variable in the `else` part of your statement.  If unless `$xmlRatesTime` is equal to `''`, `$timeStampCleaned` will not be created.  Try adding a declaration in the "else", for example:

```
if ($xmlRatesTime = '') {
    $timeStampCleaned = date('j F Y H:i', $ratesTimeStamp);
} else {
    $timeStampCleaned = ''; // add this here!
}
```

Although, generally speaking, I find this to be bad programming practice.  I would recommending declaring the variable *before* the if statement altogether, as in:

```
$timeStampCleaned = '';
if ($xmlRatesTime = '') {
    $timeStampCleaned = date('j F Y H:i', $ratesTimeStamp);
} else {
    //whatever
}
```

As a side note, did you mean `$xmlRatesTime==''` (two equal signs)?

Comment: Thanks. That's solved it :) (yes I did mean == as well! Oops)

Comment: if you wouldn't mind marking this as solved, it'd help me out ;)

Comment: Had to wait a few minutes after posting before It'd allow me to solve. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

1) read up more on variable scoping (I'm not a PHP guy, but it took me a few seconds to dig this up: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

2) The equality test you think you're doing is not an equality test at all. use `==` or `===`

Comment: Variable scoping _might be_ an issue here, but cannot be told with the info provided (he doesn't say the code is inside a function or not)